Tied notes that could be dotted
I've quite often seen tied notes that could be represented as a single dotted note, like in the example below from a guitar piece. Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

The choice seems arbitrary. Why isn’t the last up stemmed note similarly represented by two tied notes?

i’ll let someone elaborate better, but the tie is so that the beat can be easily seen. IMO The last note should also be broken into a tie and my only explanation for why it’s not is that someone wasn’t doing a good job. make sure, if you’re looking at music for models of typography or asking “why” questions, that you’re looking at professionally handled examples, Or at least competently.

This one is very clearly about the half-bar discontinuity, unlike the generic blanket question marked as duplicate. These "How to do all sorts of musical things" questions with generic answers are not good.

I'd be tempted to change the final G to an eighth tied to a quarter for basically the same reasons.

To make it easier to read rhythms, especially syncopated rhythms, 4/4 bars are commonly divided into two halves with an invisible barline. This forces visible notes to be seen on the "strong" third beat, even if the start of beat 3 is crossed by a long note. Imagine there being a line here:

There are different opinions, and it's not a hard rule, but it's quite commonly done in pop music, as you've noticed. For whole-notes, splitting is not done, except if someone wants to demonstrate how notation works or something.
Other questions discussing this:
Rhythm notation syncopation over the third beat
Dotted quarter or tied notes

It also makes it clearer that the A is meant to be held for an extra 8th note length, while the D is NOT.  If you instead used a dotted note, you might think that both notes were meant to be held, and one of them is just missing the dot, which could just be a printing error.  As someone who reads a lot of older manuscripts, often not in great condition, I can say that little things like dots on notes tend to disappear, or you get extra dots which are actually just dirt or scanning noise.  But tied notes are unambiguous.

@DarrelHoffman: An underappreciated aspect of score editing is making it clear not only what the rules of notation say a particular construct means, but also that it's intended to mean what it does.  In what would seem to be a unison passage in D minor, three voices have an a sharp accidental on an C note, and the fourth has a C with no accidental, the rules of notation would make it clear that the fourth voice is a C natural, but many performing groups might interpret the note as a misprinted C#.  If the note had a parenthesized natural in front of it, however, the intention would be clearer.

There's a hierarchy. Show the barline (that one hasn't many exceptions, except perhaps when there's a tuplet across a barline).    Show the mid-point of the bar.  Show the beats.  But allow simple syncopations.
In this case the music shows the mid-point of the bar, then allows a syncopated notation across beats 3 and 4.   When I first studied elementary music theory in the 1950s this syncopation might have been considered incorrect, and I'd have advised a student taking Grade 1 theory examination to play safe and write a tied note.   Now, that would be generally considered unnecessarily fussy.

Emphasis on simple syncopations. I'd say this particular example lies in a very small class where there's some reasonable debate about brevity vs. excessive clarity (or "fussiness" as you say). A half or dotted quarter on the second beat of a 4/4 and maybe a quarter that spans the two middle-eighths of a bar are about the only syncopations simple enough to be parsed quickly. Most music fundamentals textbooks would still likely agree that anything involving sixteenths (or smaller note values) or more complex syncopations should still show the mid-point of a 4/4 bar with ties as necessary.

@Athanasius: The way I like to look at is that in 4/4, a half note with anything in front of or after it is going to cross the mid-bar boundary, as is any dotted half note.  If a note is aligned as coarsely as it could possibly be given the qualitative presence of stuff before and/or after it, there's no need to add extra clutter showing how it crosses the midbar.

The basics is to show where the middle of the bar actually is. By making the note a dotted one, it sort of obscures that fact. By tying it across the centre of the bar, it theoretically shows where that centre is.
More and more, however, that idea is ignored, and in 4/4 in particular, notes are written which bridge that margin. Personally, I prefer to see the ties, and immediately know that something is syncopated, but others may have got used to the new idea, and aren't fazed or even bothered.

Quibble: "Fazed"? :)

@paulgarrett - it's a good quibble! 10 different meanings for phased, none of which is correct. Standing in a corner right now, with the pointy hat on. Fazed seemed so U.S. Corrected accordingly.
